# consulta a tabla relacionada pasando como parámetro el id en sql Server y asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Que tal amigos tengo una tabla como la imagen que se muestra. Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que me consulta la información de reservaciones pasando como parámetro el idCliente. Este parametro se lo paso hasta el momento fijo con numero.¿Como puedo pasar este id sin que yo se lo declare fijo teniendo en cuenta que este id no se encuentra insertado en la tabla reservaciones?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz pensado hacer una forma de elegir el cliente en tu pagina y que al elegir uno se establezca su id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropDownList tiene propiedades para establecer los campos visibles y los no visibles.

Si te entendí bien, lo que tendrías que hacer es una consulta a Clientes parecida a esta:

```
SELECT 
     [id] = idCliente, 
     [Nombre]= NombreCliente + ' ' + ApellidoPaternoCliente + ' ' + ApellidoMaternoCliente 
FROM Clientes
```

Posteriormente, digamos que tienes el objeto

DropDownList miListaClientes = new DropDownList();

Tendrías que asignarle los datos traídos en la consulta, e indicarle las siguientes propiedades:

```
miListaClientes.DataSource = ObtenerDatosConsultaClientes();
miListaClientes.DataValueField = "id"; //Columna id de la consulta de arriba
miListaClientes.DataTextField = "Nombre"; // Columna Nombre de la consulta de arriba
```

De esta manera, sólo se mostrará lo que se encuentre en la columna "Nombre" y cuando se seleccione un elemento en el DropDownList miListaClientes, podrás accesar al idCliente correspondiente:

```
public void Selection_Changed(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
    var idDelClienteSeleccionado = miListaClientes.SelectedValue;
}
```

Aquí [DropDownList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.7.2) puedes encontrar más sobre esa clase.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Según la estructura que pones el IdCliente si se encuentra en la tabla Reservaciones. Esto lo podrías solucionar utilizando un parametro de entrada en tu procedimiento de almacenado.

Comment: Hola @rockbass2560 mi idCliente si se encuentra en mi tabla reservaciones pero no esta registrado en ella y en mi procedimiento declare el parametro idCliente pero en mi aplicacion la declare fijo con numero ejemplo idCliente=5; Mi duda es como puedo traer ese id cliente si en la tabla reservaciones no hago inserciones solo actualizaciones(pero ya incluyendo ese idCliente). En mi aplicacion solo tengo dropdownlist con el codigo y los nombres de los clientes incluyendo apellidos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, como puedes tener reservaciones sin idcliente?

Comment: supongamos que quiero hacer un insert en mi tabla reservaciones ¿como mando a traer el idCliente sin que este se muestre en mi aplicacion?. Gracias por tu ayuda.